# Link Flask/Dash app to a local Bootstrap stylesheet

Tags: css, flask, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I have build an Flask/Dash application and currently I`m linking it to an external bootstrap stylesheet, like below:

```
  dash_app = dash.Dash(server=server,
                         routes_pathname_prefix='/dashapp/',
                         external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                       )
```

I would like to add some changes to CSS, so downloaded the stylesheet 
`https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css` and put it in one of my folders and I`m trying to access it locally as below, but the it is not working - my app seems not to be linked with it at all...

```
BS = "/static/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
dash_app = dash.Dash(server=server,
                         routes_pathname_prefix='/dashapp/',
                         external_stylesheets=[BS],
                       )
```

Is there smth else I should do when linking the app locally to a bootstrap stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to place your custom css in `assets` folder. Then it should work.